Question regarding range of a sqrt function
This question is in the context of the following problem.
The range of the following function is
$$f(x) = \sqrt{4-x^2} + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$$
I decided to differentiate the function to find the extrema of the function.
The derivative of the above function is
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} - \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}$$
Equating this to 0 and solving for $x$ gives us $x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$
Plugging this value into the initial function gives us the value to be $\sqrt{6}$.
How am i supposed to find the other extrema of the function, the answer for the range of the above function in my book is given to be $[\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}]$
Where does the $\sqrt{3}$ come from.
Any help would be appreciated!

Consider also for what $x$ is $f(x)$ defined, and then the image of the end points of the domain.

Sideways hint:  Solving $\frac x{\sqrt{x^2 - 1} }- \frac x{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=0$ you didn't consider $x = 0$ is solution.  What happens when $x=0$? (hee-hee, that's why I said it was a sideways hint.  )

Well the domain of the above function is $[-2, -1] \cup [1, 2]$, plugging in any one of values gives us $\sqrt{3}$, but how do we prove that this is the least value

Well, If any other term were less than $\sqrt 3$ and it didn't occur at the endpoints then... how would the terms go back up to $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 6$ without hitting a local minimum?

To check that $\sqrt 6$ is a local maximum, you might have already check the signs of $f'(x)$ before and after $x=\pm\sqrt{5/2}$.
